# JavaScript возвращает html как текст

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нашел такой вот редактор [Trumbowyg](http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/), пытаюсь скрестить его с Font-Awesome, но получаю в итоге html код кнопки, т.е. эту часть

`<i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i>`

как обычный текст.

Переопределяю кнопку так

```
btnsDef: {
    image: {
        func: ['insertImage'],
        title: 'insertImage',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i>',
    }
},
```

Тулбар строится таким образом в нем

```
// Build button pane, use o.btns and o.btnsAdd options
                $.each(btn, function (i, b) {
                    try { // Prevent buildBtn error
                        var $li = $('<li/>');

                        if (b === '|') // It's a separator
                            $li.addClass(prefix + 'separator');
                        else if (t.isSupportedBtn(b)) // It's a supported button
                            $li.append(t.buildBtn(b));

                        t.$btnPane.append($li);
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                });  

        // Build a button and his action
        buildBtn: function (n) { // n is name of the button
            var t = this,
                prefix = t.o.prefix,
                btn = t.o.btnsDef[n],
                d = btn.dropdown,
                textDef = t.lang[n] || n,

                $btn = $('<button/>', {
                    type: 'button',
                    'class': prefix + n + '-button' + (btn.ico ? ' ' + prefix + btn.ico + '-button' : ''),
                    text: btn.text || btn.title || textDef,
                    title: btn.title || btn.text || textDef + ((btn.key) ? ' (Ctrl + ' + btn.key + ')' : ''),
                    tabindex: -1,
                    mousedown: function () {
                        if (!d || $('.' + n + '-' + prefix + 'dropdown', t.$box).is(':hidden'))
                            $('body', t.doc).trigger('mousedown');

                        if (t.$btnPane.hasClass(prefix + 'disable') && !$(this).hasClass(prefix + 'active') && !$(this).parent().hasClass(prefix + 'not-disable'))
                            return false;

                        t.execCmd((d ? 'dropdown' : false) || btn.func || n, btn.param || n);

                        return false;
                    }
                });

            if (d) {
                $btn.addClass(prefix + 'open-dropdown');
                var c = prefix + 'dropdown',
                    dd = $('<div/>', { // the dropdown
                        'class': n + '-' + c + ' ' + c + ' ' + prefix + 'fixed-top'
                    });
                $.each(d, function (i, def) {
                    if (t.o.btnsDef[def] && t.isSupportedBtn(def))
                        dd.append(t.buildSubBtn(def));
                });
                t.$box.append(dd.hide());
            } else if (btn.key) {
                t.keys[btn.key] = {
                    func: btn.func || n,
                    param: btn.param || n
                };
            }

            return $btn;
        },
```

Объясните пожалуйста почему так происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется проблема кроется здесь:

```
$btn = $('<button/>', {
    ...
    text: btn.text || btn.title || textDef,
});
```

Свойство `text` у кнопки экранирует HTML и выводит чистый текст. Чтобы получилось то, что вам нужно, используйте свойство `html`:

```
html: btn.text || btn.title || textDef,
```

[Простой JSFiddle пример.](https://jsfiddle.net/jcLkohd4/1/)

Comment: Спасибо огромное !  3 часа сидел :(